# export div content to a pdf file using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have some text boxs or form like thing totally enclosed in a div. I want to provide a option to download that div content as a pdf file on button click and using only javascript.
Plz help me to solve this

Comment: please post ..what you have tried till now ??

Comment: I didnot find any thing to workout with.I tried many posts

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
function printChart() {
                pvwindow = window.open('', 'PrintWindow', ' location = 0, status = 0,  scrollbars = 1, width = 750, height = 600')
                pvwindow.document.write("<html>");
                pvwindow.document.write("<head>");
                pvwindow.document.write("</head>");
                pvwindow.document.write("<body   style='background-color:white;' onload='window.print();'>");
                pvwindow.document.write(document.getElementById("print_div").innerHTML);
                pvwindow.document.write("</body>");
                pvwindow.document.write("</html>");
                pvwindow.document.close();
            }
</script>
```

Comment: It doesnot generate pdf. Its opening a empty window

Answer (score -1):

You can have a look at this:

http://parall.ax/products/jspdf

You will not be able to convert a div into a PDF image directly, but you will be able to draw each elements one by one.

Comment: So you will have to write a script that does it for you. I will not do it for you, at least try to do something by yourself and come back if you have issues.